# How to refactor function chains for Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, streams

I have a stream of data `recordStream` that I am collecting into a `Map`.  Using a chain like this.

```
    recordStream
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(RoomSchedule::new)
        .map(roomSchedule -> roomSchedule.flipIfNeeded(processingDate))
        .filter(roomSchedule -> roomSchedule.shouldBeConsidered(processingDate))
        .flatMap(r -> r.getSlotAllocations(processingDate).parallelStream())
        .collect(toMap(
            r -> r,
            r -> 1,
            Integer::sum
        ));
```

However, I found that I was copying that code over and over again when I wanted to run tests with different streams.  I was wondering if there's a good way of refactoring the stream such that I do.

```
recordStream.makeMap()
```

so I can reuse it.

As I typed the question, the idea that popped in my head was...

```java
public class MyRecordStream extends Stream<MyStuff> {
  // (Now wondering if there's a Lomboky way of doing this wrapper)
  MyRecordStream(Stream<MyStuff> s) {
    this.s = s;
  }
  private final Stream<MyStuff> s;
  // (wrap all the other methods in stream... ugh)
  public Map makeMap() {
     return s
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(RoomSchedule::new)
            .map(roomSchedule -> roomSchedule.flipIfNeeded(processingDate))
            .filter(roomSchedule -> roomSchedule.shouldBeConsidered(processingDate))
            .flatMap(r -> r.getSlotAllocations(processingDate).parallelStream())
            .collect(toMap(
                r -> r,
                r -> 1,
                Integer::sum
            ));

  }
```

One possibility I saw was the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971597/242042 but I can't seem to get it working in a type safe manner.  The solution wraps the original stream and gives it additional operations. But yet allows you to get back the original stream.

Comment: A wrapper subclass is generally the wrong solution for this, as you are then forced to convert the *streams* to instances of *MyRecordStream*, reimplement all the methods in the wrapper, you lose access to the other methods in the instance(for example those derived from *List*)... I am not sure if there is a more elegant way, but an utility method (*public static Map getMap(Stream<MyStuff> stream)*) seems a way better option for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing the technique in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980133/java-8-extending-streamt/45971597#45971597 I created the following class (I just don't like the unchecked suppression)

```
public interface RoomScheduleStream<T extends RoomSchedule> {

    Stream<T> stream();

    @NotNull
    static <U extends RoomSchedule> RoomScheduleStream<U> of(Stream<U> delegate) {
        return () -> delegate;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default RoomScheduleStream<T> flipAndFiltered(final LocalDate processingDate) {
        return (RoomScheduleStream<T>) of(stream()
            .map(roomSchedule -> roomSchedule.flipIfNeeded(processingDate))
            .filter(roomSchedule -> roomSchedule.shouldBeConsidered(processingDate))
        );
    }

    default Stream<RoomSlotAllocation> allocations(final LocalDate processingDate) {
        return stream()
            .flatMap(r -> r.getSlotAllocations(processingDate).parallelStream());
    }

    default Map<RoomSlotAllocation, Integer> collect(final LocalDate processingDate) {
        return allocations(processingDate)
            .collect(roomCollector());
    }

    default Map<RoomSlotAllocation, Integer> filterAndCollect(final LocalDate processingDate) {
        return flipAndFiltered(processingDate)
            .collect(processingDate);
    }

    static Collector<RoomSlotAllocation, ?, Map<RoomSlotAllocation, Integer>> roomCollector() {
        return toMap(
            r -> r,
            r -> 1,
            Integer::sum
        );
    }

}
```

This allows me to refactor to

```
Map<RoomSlotAllocation, Integer> allocationMap =
   RoomScheduleStream
     .of(roomScheduleStream)
     .filterAndCollect(processingDate);
```

In addition this allows me to refactor to the following in case I want to inject a `peek` for specific tests where I want to validate the output (in this case I used `println`, but those could be asserts)

```
Map<RoomSlotAllocation, Integer> allocationMap =
  RoomScheduleStream
    .of(roomScheduleStream)
    .flipAndFiltered(processingDate)
    .allocations(processingDate)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(RoomScheduleStream.roomCollector());
```

TBH... I have no clue how this part of the code compiles, but that was derived from the original StackOverflow answer

```
static <U extends RoomSchedule> RoomScheduleStream<U> of(Stream<U> delegate) {
    return () -> delegate;
}
```

I asked a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674376/how-does-delegate-wrap-a-stream) about that construct

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obvious solution of an utility method (already mentioned in my comment), I think the most straightforward idea to keep it OO is to implement your own *Collector*; *Collector.of* provides a straightforward way:

```
Collector collector = Collector.of(
   () -> new HashMap<Record, Integer>(),
   (result, record) -> {
       // All of the filters and transformations in your chain.
       // If the element is filtered out, exit doing nothing.
       // If the element is not filtered out:
       Integer total = result.get(transformedRecord);
       if (total == null) {
         total = 1;
       } else {
         total = total + 1;
       }
       result.put(transformedRecord, total);
     },
     (result1, result2) -> {
       result1.addAll(result2);
       return result1;
     });
```

and

```
recordStream.collect(collector);
```

Of course, to reuse code you can create a factory/builder to provide the collection. Or you can even implement the Collector yourself with those functions.

In any case, remember that *streams* are not silver bullets. They are thought to make simple operations easy to write and read, but if using them gets complicated then you may find that they are not the right tool.

Comment: Yah I had something similar before, but then this "collector" got too large so I wanted to break it apart so I can add additional filtering and other stream operations if needed.  Plus it is easier to explain

Comment: You should make up your mind. "Reusing the code" often conflicts with "I wanted to break it apart" and "add additional filtering and operations". Encapsulating the logic means losing control of it (from the client code POV) and making it less flexible (unless you want to create your own framework to support all the options that you think you need).

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano - but, if you can find a way to generalize certain procedures, you may be able to break it apart. Try to make a distinction between core logic and case-specific logic; then you can try and make the latter be supplied externally as lambdas. But if you don't need that much flexibility, I wouldn't avoid utility methods (and these can also accept lambdas, BTW).

Comment: I was able to break the functions themselves apart, but the operation chain can get long, so basically I want to group two or more operations